# How to select and output text in a string

Tags: grep, string, output

I need to select and output into a file some text contained in a specific string.

Let's say the string is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP

What would be a command to extract what is after ABCDEF and before K? (i.e. GHIJ only) to another file?

I tried with grep command but due to my poor understanding of its complexity it failed every time. I must be missing something very basic.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that you are programming using a shell, such as `bash`.

You will need `sed`.

e.g.

```
sed -re 's/^ABCDEF(.*)K.*/\1/'
```

This uses grep to search and replace `s/thing to find as regexp/thing to replace it with/`

`\1` means replace with 1st bracketed expression.

Comment: You don't need `-e` when you're using `-r`. And `-r` is GNU extension. There isn't `GNU sed` everywhere. `-r` is easier for understanding, but without it script is more portable. So, it can be `sed 's/^ABCDEF\(.*\)K.*/\1/'`.

Answer (score 4):

On finding a match, grep prints the whole matched line. To make it print only the matched text, you can use `-o` switch. But, this prints the whole matched string within the line. To make it print what you need, you should use [look-behind and look-ahead assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions). This requires a grep with PCRE support.

```
> grep -Po '(?<=ABCDEF).+(?=K)' <<< 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'
GHIJ
```

Explanation:

- `-P` Enable perl compatible regular expression
- `-o` Print only the matched text, not whole line
- `(?<=ABCDEF)` Positive look-behind assertion for matching ABCDEF
- `(?=K)` Positive look-ahead assertion for matching K
- `.+` Match everything between the above assertions

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with either of the solutions posted, but you can do this in pure Bash if you like.

Given a string with your value:

```
echo $myStr 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
```

You can do:

```
echo $(expr match "$myStr" '.*F\(.*\)K.*')
GHIJ
```